# Spring Boot @JmsListener consuming messages without msg.acknowledge() even though Session is set to CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

Spring Boot `@JmsListener` is consuming messages without `msg.acknowledge()` even though the `Session` is set to `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`. I have tried setting `spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=CLIENT` in `application.properties`, but it's no use.

```java
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;

@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class MQConfiguration {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Bean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setErrorHandler(t -> {
            logger.warn("An error has occurred in the transaction");
            logger.error(t.getCause().getMessage());
        });
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency("1");
        factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
        
        return factory;
    }    
}

@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination = "school.XXXX.request.clock-in", concurrency = "1")
public void consumeMessageFromMQ(String message, Message msg) throws Throwable {
    -----------
}
```

Spring Version is:

```xml
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.15</version>
   <relativePath />
</parent>
<properties>
   <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Maybe I am confused.  You can consume as many messages as you like from a destination without acknowledging any of them.  Acknowledging a message acknowledges all previously consumed messages (you just need to ACK the last message).   If killing your process results in the messages being returned to the queue, then thos messages had been read, but not acknowledged.

Comment: I wanted ActiveMQ Artemis to hold my message till acknowledged. I had no problems during transaction processing and after saving the message info to the DB, I wanted to acknowledge it. JMS listens to the message and then removes it from the queue. I wanted to know how to keep the message in the queue until I acknowledged it.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added my spring framework version and ActiveMQ Artemis version. Please suggest which version works fine. We will update on that.